# how to detect power button click 3 times in android in background in service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, android-event, onkeypress

I want to detect power button click event in application which has service running in background.

However i am able to detect long click of power button in service.
now i want to detect that power button click three times in background.

(Using **draw over other apps**) //that makes logic

I searched it for google that gives no result , is there anyway or logic which we can implement for this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the fully working [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051157/how-to-override-double-or-even-3-times-clicking-power-button-or-even-volume-up-d/57056408#57056408) to this question